# How to make a Sorting algorithm Java for age and name at the same time?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have made a lot of search at the Internet for making a sorting algorithm, but I can only find algorithms to sort 1 thing. I have to sort 2 things at the same time.

The stdIN look likes:

```
name, last name
birth year
dead year
name,last name
birth year
dead year
```

I will a sorting algorithm to get the following output:

```
name, last name age
name,last name age
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your solution is likely boiling down to "Create a custom class for your data, and make it implement Comparable, which will do the ordering you need when using Collections.sort()"

Comment: Either create a `Person` class that encapsulates all this data and have it implement Comparable or use a custom Comparator.  You may want to start with [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/).

Comment: "I have made a lot of search at the Internet for making a sorting algorithm": I do not believe you. There are numerous similar questions on this site alone.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer generally and you can apply this to your situation.
Lets assume you have a class Person:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
//constructor
    String name;
    int age;
    public String getName(){...}
    Public int getAge(){...}
}
```

In order to compare objects which you have created (and therefore it is unclear as to which of the members the objects should be compared by) you will need to create a Comparator!
This specific Comparator will sort by age first, then by name. You may, of course, change that to your needs(or even add more conditions to sort by).

```
static class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person>
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
            int ans;
            Integer age1 = p1.getAge();
            Integer age2 = p2.getAge();
            ans = age1.compareTo(age2);
            if(ans!=0) //0 means they're equal
                 return ans;
            else{ 
                String name1; = p1.getName();
                String name2; = p2.getName();
                return name1.CompareTo(name2); 
            }
```

Your sort function looks something like:

```
public void order(List<Person> persons){
    PersonComparator pc = new PersonComparator()
    Collections.sort(persons,pc);
}
```

The persons List will be ordered first by age then by name.

- Sort method internally uses ASCII value to sort elements therefore you need to make sure names start with capitals.

Integer/String compareTo info [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_compareto.htm)
collection.sort info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) - This will do the hard work for you as long as you give it the tool to compare by